# PlayFrameWork 2.6- JAVA WS- send and receive json data

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.6

How to send data through a post in the url (using ws (url) .post ()) and how to manipulate that data in the same application

I'm using ws.
and this code to send message via post

```
    public class WebService implements WSBodyReadables, WSBodyWritables {
     private final WSClient ws;

@Inject
public WebService(WSClient ws) {
    this.ws = ws;
    JsonNode json = Json.newObject()
            .put("key1", "value1")
            .put("key2", "value2");

    ws.url("http://localhost:9000/web").post(json);


}


// ...
```

}

and I want to receive this data in the controller, I am using this code:

```
    public class WebServiceController extends Controller{
@Inject  WSClient ws;
@Inject
Materializer materializer;
private Server server;
private Content response;




public CompletionStage<Result> web() {

    return ws.url("http://localhost:9000/web").get().thenApply(response ->
            ok("Feed title: " + response.asJson().findPath("title").asText())
    );
}
```

}

But I get this error when accessing the url

'CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing JSON from WS response wsBody'

I'm new to playframework, I need to do a webservice where I can give a post with some information, and then access that url and capture that information. Please help me